# Checking IF a column's values in a pandas df are in a list

Tags: python, pandas

I've initialized a list containing the following values:

```
list = ['Umbrella', 'Umbrella'].
```

I also have a dataframe with 4 columns. I would like to initiate a conditional IF/else statement whereby if Column A value is in the list then I would like it to perform a sum operation.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['10/2/2011', '11/2/2011', '12/2/2011', '13/2/2011'], 
               'Product':['Umbrella', 'Umbrella', 'Badminton', 'Shuttle'], 
               'Last Price':[1200, 1500, 1600, 352], 
               'Updated Price':[1250, 1450, 1550, 400], 
               'Discount':[10, 10, 10, 10]})
```

''''
However I've tried the following code however it is not working:

```
if df['Product'].isin(list):
    Cumulative_Spend = df.groupby('Product')['Last Price'].sum()  
else:
    Calibrated = df.groupby('Product')['Last Price'].sum()
```

Should the condition meet(in the list initialized), I would like to aggregate the sum of Last Prices for each item and if condition does not meet then I would like to take the Last Price value of that item and store it in a different list called Calibrated.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected output, don't leave it to us to have to guess what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm guessing you mean to do something involving `df.where`, `df.filter` or boolean masking, but as stated, you haven't given us enough detail. In the code snippet provided, your if and else results are exactly the same, you haven't done anything to the dataframe to change the `groupby`

Comment: ps. Dont use `list` as a variable name, since it's an reserved word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there, 2 things: you need to filter instead of if and you need tail in the second one instead of sum, here goes:

```
import pandas as pd

l = ['Umbrella', 'Umbrella']

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['10/2/2011', '11/2/2011', '12/2/2011', '13/2/2011'], 
           'Product':['Umbrella', 'Umbrella', 'Badminton', 'Shuttle'], 
           'Last Price':[1200, 1500, 1600, 352], 
           'Updated Price':[1250, 1450, 1550, 400], 
           'Discount':[10, 10, 10, 10]}) 

Cumulative_Spend = df[df['Product'].isin(l)].groupby('Product')['Last Price'].sum() 
Calibrated = df[~df['Product'].isin(l)].groupby('Product')['Last Price'].tail(1)
```

Comment: This works! Thank you. Curious, why could I not search the list via the df column using the IF condition ? Is it because it is different datatypes? Just trying to understand the logic...

Comment: you probably could, but it means iterating through a list and filtering the df each time for the specific case, here you just filter twice

Comment: regarding the calculation of ''Calibrated'' on your formula above 
`Calibrated = df[~df['Product'].isin(l)].groupby('Product')['Last Price'].tail(1)`

when a new file is picked up in the loop for processing it seems not be including new products on the most current list as the numbers when calculating by hand are not adding up - unsure why that is. The tilde from my understanding produces all the products not in the list to then perform the groupby calculation - is that correct?